# How to get the information of pdf file on storage in android device and display it on to the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf

I am trying to get the information about the pdf files on my android 11 device and display it on my screen How can I do that?
and also we could open the pdf file after clicking on it...

Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get pdf file content you can make use of itext library.

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

This library will help you to fetch the content of any  pdf document. Please follow the below code for reference

```
try {
      String text="";
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pdf file path");
      int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
      for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
           text= text+PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; 
      }
      System.out.println(text);
      reader.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
}
```

at the end you will get pdf content as text and you can show it on screen.